# EF Core 8 does not update the column in the database table if there is an index on the column

Tags: entity-framework-core

I found a strange behavior in updating an entity with EF Core 8. In the `Anagrafi` entity, I defined the following index on the `CodFisc` field:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Anagrafi>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasIndex(e => e.CodFisc, "IX_Anagrafi_CodFisc").HasFillFactor(90);
}
```

This is an example of code that should update the `CodFisc` field, which originally contains the value "aaa," with "AAA":

```
[HttpPut("test/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test (int id, AnagraficaCompletaResource anag)
{
    var entity = await genericDataService.FindAsync<Anagrafi>(id);
    //entity.CodFisc equals "aaa"
            
    entity.CodFisc = "AAA";
    await genericDataService.SaveChangesAsync();

    entity = await genericDataService.FindAsync<Anagrafi>(id);
    //entity.CodFisc equals "AAA" but the column in the database table is still "aaa"
    return Ok();
}
```

Essentially, if I update the `CodFisc` field with the same value but a different casing, the column is not updated. If I completely change the value, the column in the database table is updated correctly.

If I remove the index definition in the entity, the first update also works correctly.

GenericDataService simply do this:

```
public async Task<T> FindAsync<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    return await DataContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
}
public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
{
    await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Post the actual EF Core code and the DbContext configuration. EF 8 has no problem with indexes. The question *doesn't* contain any EF Core code though, just calls to a `genericDataService`. EF Core's DbContext is already generic. It's not a database connection, it's a multi-entity Unit of Work.

Comment: @marc_s this shouldn't prevent EF from updating the row. The `UPDATE` query is generated by the DbContext which sees that `CodFisc` changed. The DbContext itself doesn't even know what the database collation is unless the OP set it with `UseCollation`. Which is possible

Comment: Have you tried the latest daily build?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you're correct - the collation doesn't prevent EF Core from updating the column from `aaa` to `AAA` - and neither does an index on that column. There must be something else happening here that interferes with the update ....

Comment: I updated my question adding GenericDataService.cs

 If i comment entity.HasIndex(e => e.CodFisc, "IX_Anagrafi_CodFisc").HasFillFactor(90); all works fine

Comment: @ErikEJ i updated to the last verson with Nuget Package Manager (8.0.1)